# Why is Application.Current.Windows always empty in WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a program which has a custom Main method (i.e. not auto generated from App.xaml) and everything is working with no issues except for one thing; I need to get the collection of all windows and the `WindowCollection` accessed via Application.Current.Windows is always empty (non-null but count == 0).

Other properties of the Application instance such as MainWindow are available but for some reason this collection is never added to. Have I missed wiring something up?

As a side note, is there an event anywhere that notifies whenever a new window is opened in a WPF app?

Comment: Is your Window instantiated on a background thread, or are you trying to call `Application.Current.Windows` from a background thread? Both of these are possible reasons why there's a count of zero. More info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx

Comment: I just had a play with this and confirmed that both the window instantiation and the code using the `WindowCollection ` are on the same thread. To be doubly sure I actually dispatched the lookup code to the MainWindow dispatcher thread and didn't even see the MainWindow in the collection

Comment: Oh, and the thread in this case is the main (STA) thread of the application, not a background thread